# Semicontinuity of fiber dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The following two on commutative algebra are true?

Let $S$ be a f.g. algebra over a field $k$.
Let $e$ be an integer.
Then
(1) There is an ideal $I\subset S$ such that if $Q$ is a maximal ideal of $S$ then

$dim S_Q\ge e$ iff $Q\supset I.$

(2) if $S=S_0\oplus S_1\oplus \cdots$ is a graded algebra, f.g. over $S_0=k$ then

$dim S\ge e.$

---

EDIT. (1) is done by Matt.  I rewite (2).

Is it trivially true when $R$ is a field? If not, how should we modify it?

Theorem 14.8b(Eisenbud CA p316)

Let $S$ be a f.g. algebra over a Noetheian ring  $R$.
Let $e$ be an integer.
Then

(2) if $S=S_0\oplus S_1\oplus \cdots$ is a graded algebra, f.g. over $S_0=R$ then there exists an ideal $J$ of $R$ such that for any prime ideal $P\subset R$,

$dim K(R/P)\otimes S\ge e$ iff $P\supset J.$

Here $K(\cdot)$ means a quotient field.

Comment: Let me explain my motivation. (2) seems to be wrong for $S=k[x]$. But Eisenbud's book CA p316L-2 says it is true. Ii is in proof for main theorem of elimination theory.

Comment: The original one is as follows. Is it trivially true when $R$ is a field?

Theorem 14.8

Let $S$ be a f.g. algebra over a Noetheian ring  $R$.
Let $e$ be an integer.
Then

(1) There is an ideal $I\subset S$ such that if $Q$ is a maximal ideal of $S$ and$P:=R\cap Q$  then 

$dim S_Q/PS_Q\ge e$ iff $Q\supset I.$

(2) if $S=S_0\oplus S_1\oplus \cdots$ is a graded algebra, f.g. over $S_0=R$ then there exists an ideal $J$ of $R$ such that for any prime ideal $P\subset R$,

$dim S\ge e$ iff $P\supset J.$

Comment: Typo fixed. The original one is as follows. Is it trivially true when $R$ is a field?

Theorem 14.8

Let $S$ be a f.g. algebra over a Noetheian ring  $R$.
Let $e$ be an integer.
Then

(1) There is an ideal $I\subset S$ such that if $Q$ is a maximal ideal of $S$ and$P:=R\cap Q$  then 

$dim S_Q/PS_Q\ge e$ iff $Q\supset I.$

(2) if $S=S_0\oplus S_1\oplus \cdots$ is a graded algebra, f.g. over $S_0=R$ then there exists an ideal $J$ of $R$ such that for any prime ideal $P\subset R$,

$dim K(R/P)\otimes S\ge e$ iff $P\supset J.$

Comment: Dear Tom, I don't understand (2).  You seem to have let $e$ be any integer, so certainly it can't be that $\dim S_0 \geq e$ in general (just take $e$ to be bigger than $\dim S_0$!).   If $I$ is not the unit ideal (for a given value of $e$), *then* (2) is true.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt E. Do you mean Theorem 14.8 is wrong?

Comment: $I$ and $J$ are chosen depending on $e$.

Comment: Dear Tom, I don't know what Thm. 14.8 is, but I doubt it.  But just look at your statement: in question (2), what relationship is there between $e$ and $S$?  I don't think that Eisenbud would make the (obviously false) claim that the dimension of any f.g. graded $k$-algebra can be bounded below by an arbitrary integer.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Tom, Reading over your comments, I now see what Thm. 4.8 says.  The point is that if $e$ is too large, then $J$ will be the unit ideal of $k$, rather than the $0$ ideal.  In other words, in the case when $R = k$ (a field), one takes $J$ to be the zero ideal if $e \leq \dim S$, and one takes $J$ to be the unit ideal otherwise.  So in this case, yes, the statement is trivial.  Regards,

Comment: P.S.  It's not surprising the statement is trivial in the case $R = k$.  After all, this is a statement about dimensions of fibres.  When $R = k$, Spec $k$ has a single point, so there is only fibre, and its dimension is whatever it is. When the fibre can't vary, there is not much non-trivial to say about the dimension of the fibres behaves under variation!

Comment: Oh, it is trivial! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding (1):
Look at Spec $S$.  It is a union of finitely many irred. components, say $X_i$, of dimension $d_i$.  Then the localisation of $S$ at $Q$ has dimension equal to the max of the $d_i$ for those $i$ for which $Q \in X_i$.  Thus it has dimension $\geq e$ provided that $Q$ lies in at least one $X_i$ for which $d_i \geq e$.  So, if we let $I$ be the ideal that cuts out those components of dimension $\geq e$, 
then $Q \supset I$ iff $S_Q$ has dimension $\geq e$.

If $I$ is not the unit ideal, i.e. if there actually *is* a component of dimension $\geq e$, then certainly $\dim S \geq e$.  So this proves (a corrected variant of) (2).

Comment: Sorry. My background knowledge is only Eisrnbud book p1-316 without some exercises skipped.
So, I know the definition of Spec S only. Irreducible component of dimension $d$?

Comment: Oh! There are only finitely many minimal ideals $I$. Let $d_i:=dim R/I.$

Comment: Ok. I think I understood (1). Thank you.